# Equivalent Mosfet Recommendation

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, pcb-fabrication

We need to use a mosfet(AP9963GP), but cant supply it. So can we use this mosfet (IXF220N06T3) instead or anything else that you recommend?

Comment: Product recommendation questions not allowed here :-(. | Listv the key parameters that matter and then look at suppliers election guides  eg www.digikey.com

Answer (score 1):

The job of a Design or Component Engineer is to find an equivalent or better that fits in the same form or can be designed to fit.

What are your requirements? free advice?
[image]

TO-220

Unfortunately all the new, best FETs are in SMD. Can you use that?

Comment: Here we have a mosfet with the specs :                                                                                                         - Vds = 40V, Vgs = +/-20V, Id = continious 160A, Gate treshold voltage = min :1, max : 3V                      Now I need a equivelent mosfet to replace this one which will be used in low-voltage applications,

Comment: Low DS or low GS? then how low, if GS?